# Spring batch - @StepScope throws IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118

Tags: java, xml, spring, annotations, spring-batch

I'm trying to convert a project that was made using spring batch xml to annotations and I'm having some trouble with the reader while using the annotation `@StepScope`.

Here's the xml code I'm trying to convert:

```
    <batch:job ...>
    
        ....
    
        <batch:step  id="springBatchCommonStep" abstract="true"
            job-repository="coreBatchJobRepository" />
            
        <batch:step id="processReportItemsStep" parent="springBatchCommonStep">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="appTransactionManager">
                <batch:chunk
                        reader="collectReportMultiResourceItemReader"
                        processor="reportLineProcessor"
                        writer="reportLineItemWriter"
                        commit-interval="${batch.collect.commit.interval}"
                        skip-limit="${batch.collect.skip.limit}">
                    <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                        <batch:include class="xx.xx.exception.common.InvalidXmlException"/>
                        <batch:include class="xx.xx.exception.collection.InvalidDomainException"/>
                        <batch:include class="xx.xx.exception.collection.InvalidDataLogException"/>
                    </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
            <batch:end on="COMPLETED"/>
            <batch:fail on="*" />
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="collectReportProcessingListener"/>
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:step>
        
        ....
        
    </batch:job>


    <bean id="collectReportItemReader"
          class="xx.xx.CollectReportItemReader" scope="step">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="declarationReportItemJaxb2Marshaller"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="collectReportMultiResourceItemReader"
          class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader"
          scope="step">
        <property name="resources" value="file:${batch.collect.folder.input}/*.xml"/>
        <property name="delegate" ref="collectReportItemReader"/>
    </bean>
```

And here with the annotations:

```
    @Bean
    public Step processReportItemsStep(
            @Value("${batch.collect.commit.interval}") Integer commitInterval,
            @Value("${batch.collect.skip.limit}") Integer skipLimit,
            MultiResourceItemReader<CollectReportItemWrapper> collectReportMultiResourceItemReader,
            CompositeItemProcessor<CollectReportItemWrapper, ReportLine> reportLineProcessor,
            CollectReportItemWriter reportLineItemWriter,
            CollectReportProcessingListener collectReportProcessingListener) throws Exception {
        return steps.get("processReportItemsStep")
                .repository(factory.getJobRepository())
                .transactionManager(appTransactionManager)
                .<CollectReportItemWrapper, ReportLine>chunk(commitInterval)

                .reader(collectReportMultiResourceItemReader)
                .processor(reportLineProcessor)
                .writer(reportLineItemWriter)

                .listener((ItemReadListener<CollectReportItemWrapper>) collectReportProcessingListener)
                .faultTolerant()
                    .skipLimit(skipLimit)
                    .skip(InvalidXmlException.class)
                    .skip(InvalidDomainException.class)
                    .skip(InvalidDataLogException.class)
                    .listener((SkipListener<CollectReportItemWrapper, CollectReportProcessingListener>) collectReportProcessingListener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public CollectReportItemReader collectReportItemReader(
            Jaxb2Marshaller declarationReportItemJaxb2Marshaller) {
        return new CollectReportItemReader(declarationReportItemJaxb2Marshaller);
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public MultiResourceItemReader<CollectReportItemWrapper> collectReportMultiResourceItemReader(
            @Value("file:${batch.collect.folder.input}/*.xml") Resource[] inputResources,
            CollectReportItemReader collectReportItemReader) {
        MultiResourceItemReader<CollectReportItemWrapper> m = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
        m.setResources(inputResources);
        m.setDelegate(collectReportItemReader);
        return m;
    }
```

and here a reduced version of my reader. If more information is needed, just tell me:

```
import xx.xx.common.BusyAbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader;
import xx.xx.exception.collection.InvalidDataLogException;
import xx.xx.exception.collection.InvalidDomainException;
import xx.xx.exception.collection.InvalidLifeCycleStateException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.oxm.Unmarshaller;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CollectReportItemReader
        extends BusyAbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader<CollectReportItemWrapper>
        implements ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<CollectReportItemWrapper>, InitializingBean {

    private Unmarshaller unmarshaller;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public CollectReportItemReader(Unmarshaller unmarshaller) {
        setName(ClassUtils.getShortName(CollectReportItemReader.class));
        this.unmarshaller = unmarshaller;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(this.unmarshaller, "The Unmarshaller must not be null.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doOpen() throws Exception {
        super.doOpen();
    }

    @Override
    public void doClose() throws Exception {
        super.doClose();
        // Remove the treated file (if still present)
        if (resource != null) {
            FileUtils.deleteQuietly(resource.getFile());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Move to next fragment and map it to item.
     */
    @Override
    protected CollectReportItemWrapper doRead() throws Exception {
        if (noInput) {
            return null;
        }

        return getNextFragment(xmlStreamReader);
    }

    private CollectReportItemWrapper getNextFragment(XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader)
            throws XMLStreamException, IOException, OnegateActionDeleteOnReportOrDataException,
            InvalidLifeCycleStateException, InvalidDomainException, InvalidDataLogException {
        CollectReportItemWrapper wrappedItem = new CollectReportItemWrapper(
                resource);
        CollectReportDto report = new CollectReportDto();

        while (xmlStreamReader.hasNext()) {
            int eventCode = xmlStreamReader.next();

            // xml read logic here
        }

        noInput = !xmlStreamReader.hasNext();

        return wrappedItem;
    }

    /**
     * In strict mode the reader will throw an exception on
     * {@link #open(org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext)} if the input resource does not exist.
     *
     * @param strict false by default
     */
    public void setStrict(boolean strict) {
        this.strict = strict;
    }

    @Override
    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at xx.xx.test.runner.IxgBatchIntegrationTestRunner.methodBlock(IxgBatchIntegrationTestRunner.java:58)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at xx.xx.test.statement.BeforeTestClassStatement.evaluate(BeforeTestClassStatement.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'collectReportItemReader' defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [xx.xx.jobs.CollectOneGateDeclarationReportJobConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:102)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean.setBeanFactory(ScopedProxyFactoryBean.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1534)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
    at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:206)
    ... 46 more
```

If I remove the `@StepScope` annotation, the job starts, but it loads the reader too early, it will load only the xml files that are there while starting the application instead of when the job is running

After some time on Google I figured it out that the exception happens because I'm doing a proxy of a proxy. I just have no idea how to fix it.

Maybe I'm missing something? Maybe some configuration?
This is the first batch I'm trying to convert, so it's possible that I missed something

Comment: can you provide the step code which make use of that reader?

Comment: @gaetanTEMATE sure! I added it to the original question

Comment: Is CollectReportItemReader, your custom created ItemReader. If yes, then can you check if that class is final or add the code of that class here?

Comment: @AnkitChauhan yes, it's my custom class and it isn't final. I added the relevant class code in the original question